# Проблема с фильтрацией Select2 в GridView

Tags: php, yii, gridview

Есть 2 базы данных
Одна имеет id,serial_number, store_id
Вторая только id
Связь идет один store_id к многим id
Задача - настроить фильтр на store_id ( вывод всех устройств на складе)
Проблема - не работает, не могу понять почему код ругается на строку

```
'attribute' => 'store_id',
```

Вот реализация поиска

```
public function search($params){
        {

            $query = Device::find()->with('device');

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query
            ]);

            $this->load($params);
            
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,
                'serial_number' => $this->serial_number,

            ]);

            return $dataProvider;
        }
    }
```

Вот реализация
GridView

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'serial_number',
        [

            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return Html::a(
                    $model->store_id,
                    '#',
                    [
                        'data-store-id' => $model->store_id,
                        'data-target' => 'modal',
                    ]
                );
            },


            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'attribute' => 'store_id', //
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Store::find()->all(),'store_id','id'),
                'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                'hideSearch' => true,
                'value' =>'devices',
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Select a store ...'
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'selectOnClose' => true,
                ],
            ])
        ],
        'about',
        'created_at',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

А вот контроллер

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new SearchDevices();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render(
            'index',
            [
    //                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    //                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]
        );
    }
```

```
                     _____________________________________________
```

Comment: *"почему код ругается на строку"* --- было бы правильным привести текст ошибки... Ещё было бы правильно указать чей именно виджет Select2 используется..... а ещё было бы правильно закинуть текст ошибки в переводчик, если ангийский текст непонятен.

Comment: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: frontend\models\SearchDevices::store_id

Comment: Виджет https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2

Comment: Возможно надо `store_id` прописать в `rules` для модели.... причём не только основной модели, но и для search модели